# Nautilus is very slow after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: nautilus

Since upgrading to 20.04, when I change directories I get at least two seconds of the blue&red beach ball cursor before the contents of the new directory are displayed. And sometimes it's dozens of seconds.

As a workaround I've switched to Nemo, but I mildly prefer Nautilus, so if ever there was an easy fix I would take it.

Comment: Nautilus in 20.04 should be much better in that respect then previous versions of nautilus. Do you have the same issue in a fresh account on the system? If yes, I would reconsider a fresh install.